# Order by in mysql using second table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two tables, one is a list os stores and attributes, the second is a list of allocationsa based on these attributes.
The attribute table (stores_metadata)

```
| key | store_key | field | value
| 1   | 1         | size  | Large
| 2   | 1         | dist  | Midlands
| 3   | 2         | size  | Medium
| 4   | 3         | dist  | South
```

The allocation table (allocation)

```
| key | ticket_key | field | value | count
| 1   | 1          | size  | Large | 10
| 2   | 1          | size  | Medium| 5
```

I've managed to get the allocations working using the code:

```
SELECT store_key, quantity FROM 
allocation

INNER JOIN store_metadata
  ON allocation.`field` = store_metadata.`field`
    AND allocation.`value` = store_metadata.`value`
```

This returns a list of the stores and how many items they should recieve, what I now need to do it order the stores by the distribution attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which table does this field exists?

Comment: Distribution is a entry in the field column of the stores_metadata table.

Comment: Sorry, Distribution is in the database as dist.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't asked very well.

To perform ordering by any column in your result set add `ORDER BY [column]` to the end of the query. E.g.

```
SELECT store_key, quantity FROM 
allocation

INNER JOIN store_metadata
  ON allocation.`field` = store_metadata.`field`
    AND allocation.`value` = store_metadata.`value`
    ORDER BY allocation.`field`;
```

Comment: i don't want to sort by a column, I want to sort by the value of an attribute in the metadata table.